# SharePoint Server 2010 to the Cloud (Azure)

Tags: deployment, recommendations

As part of our implementation of SharePoint 2010 (Server), I am tasked with investigating the option to deploy SharePoint 2010 via the cloud.  Does anyone have the benefits and/or limitations for migrating a SharePoint farm consisting of up to seven servers (initially) to Windows Azure?  If Azure is not the right cloud product, what IaaS provider would be a better fit?

Is there a significant benefit to placing the WFE servers in the cloud pointing back to App Servers on-premises?

I am sure there are plenty of questions I am neglecting, so please be free to offer as much ancillary information as possible.

Comment: You probably want to have a look at Office 365 for more options for hosted SharePoint.

Comment: Office 365/SharePoint Online does not provide a true SharePoint Server infrastructure.  All you would have access to is the creation of new site collections.  Hardly a full product offering.

Comment: a) You haven't stated in your question what you need. b) If you have enough seats (> ~100,000 users) you will able to negotiate the rest of the farm's capabilities.

Comment: a) Does anyone have the benefits and/or limitations for migrating a SharePoint farm consisting of up to seven servers (initially) to Windows Azure? If Azure is not the right cloud product, what IaaS provider would be a better fit?

b) Not sure I have an answer.  I know what the farm's requirements are.

From what I gather Windows Azure is not a good choice as it is not a typical IaaS provider.

Comment: @user1336 ("All you would have access to is the creation of new site collections") Are you sure? As far as I can see - e.g. from [SharePoint Online for Office 365: Developer Guide](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=4387e030-73dc-48e7-ac95-abc043b9335a) - you can customize/develop a whole bunch of things on SP Online (not _all_ things you can do on SP).

Comment: superjos, you are correct.  The farm level configuration options would not be available.  Thus, things like workflow controlled site provisioning become trickier to handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't host SharePoint on Azure, and putting the WFEs in the cloud with on-premise SQL would not be workable from a performance stand-point or a supported configuration. If you want a cloud hosting solution and Office365 Enterprise won't fit the bill consider Amazon or Rackspace virtual servers. Make sure you contact Microsoft to validate the licensing required to cover your farm - with cloud hosting it can get tricky.

Comment: Also VM's in Azure are stateless which is not suppoerted by SharePoint!

Comment: This should actually be possible at some point. My company is a close partner with the Azure team and have a proof of concept Azure (hosted VM) running SharePoint.

Comment: I have heard "rumors" that they are getting close to proofing out SP in Azure.  So I asked the question to see if anyone else can substantiate these.