# SharePoint and the new Azure AD - will it run?

Tags: 2010, 2013, hosting, azure

*(I know this has been asked partly before: [SharePoint Server 2010 to the Cloud (Azure)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11936/sharepoint-server-2010-to-the-cloud-azure) and here [Sharepoint Development Environment Windows Azure](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/63102/sharepoint-development-environment-windows-azure) but this is slightly different)*

I see that yesterday the Azure AD was released. http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2013/04/08/windows-azure-active-directory-general-availability-new-backup-service-web-site-monitoring-and-diagnostic-improvements.aspx

Would this make the Azure a preferd platform for hosting a small farm? I'm asking a two part question here:

- A) Will it work with the Azure ad?
- B) Is it suitable both as a development and
  production environment - that is, what are possible traps that I should watch out for?

Regards

Larsi